# Caesar Cipher Code Python printing on separate lines

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

The code below works fine, however the message prints onto separate lines once it has been encrypted. For example if I type: abc with the shift of 1 it encrypts it but prints it back as:

```
b
c
d
```

And I don't understand why. I want it to print as:

```
 bcd
```

Here is the code:

```
print("Welcome to the Code-Breaking/Making Software")
print("This program uses something called a Caesar Cipher.")

Message = (input("Please enter the message you wish to Encrypt >> "))
Shift = int(input("Please enter the shift for your message >> "))

for x in Message:
    OrdMessage = ord(x) 
    ShiftedMessage = OrdMessage + Shift
    NewMessage = chr(ShiftedMessage)
    NewMessageList = list(NewMessage)
    print("".join(NewMessageList))
```

Comment: you are printing each char within your for loop.

Comment: How would I fix that then? By adding the print outside of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation matters and you shouldn't create new list of `NewMessage` everytime

```
print("Welcome to the Code-Breaking/Making Software")
print("This program uses something called a Caesar Cipher.")

Message = (input("Please enter the message you wish to Encrypt >> "))
Shift = int(input("Please enter the shift for your message >> "))

NewMessageList = []
for x in Message:
    OrdMessage = ord(x) 
    ShiftedMessage = OrdMessage + Shift
    NewMessage = chr(ShiftedMessage)
    NewMessageList.append(NewMessage)
print("".join(NewMessageList))
```

Comment: That works thanks! Can you maybe explain the commands you used as I am not familiar. (College Student)

Comment: Only command used here is `append`. What it does it appends element to list. Read more in documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: What about NewMessageList = []
Does that just assign the variable to nothing?

Comment: not nothing. [] is empty list, () is empty tuple, {} is empty dictonary, set() is empty set, list() is empty list and so on...

Comment: I still don't get what append actually does.

Comment: Appends passed item. In docs: `Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].` Plenty of clean explanations on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend

Answer (score 0):

you should change the following part;

```
print("".join(NewMessageList), end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

What happening was is that for each charachter it was running the loop and printing the answer, now I have collected all the encrypted letter and clubbed them as one in the end and printed it.

it at first initialize an empty list with `NewMessage = []` and then for every letter that we get encrypted it adds to that empty list using `.append()` and at end print all by `''.join(NewMessage)`

```
print("Welcome to the Code-Breaking/Making Software")
print("This program uses something called a Caesar Cipher.")

Message = (input("Please enter the message you wish to Encrypt >> "))
Shift = int(input("Please enter the shift for your message >> "))

NewMessage = []
for x in Message:
    OrdMessage = ord(x) 
    ShiftedMessage = OrdMessage + Shift
    NewMessage.append(chr(ShiftedMessage)) 
print(''.join(NewMessage))
```

Comment: What does NewMessage = [] do and .append?

Comment: it at first initialize an empty list with `NewMessage = []` and then for every letter that we get encrypted it adds to that empty list using `.append()` and at end print all by `''.join(NewMessage)`